# Drawing not available and PDF not available

Tags: us

In reference to the patent: [US20150244345](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150244345)

Why are the drawings not uploaded? In this patent, PDF is not available to see or download.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides two portals for viewing patents. The one you used (www.google.com/patents) frequently has problems displaying figures. The better Google site is [patents.google.com](https://patents.google.com). Here is a link to [US20150244345 on patents.google.com](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150244345A1/en). You will find both figures an a downloadable pdf. In my opinion, an even better site for searching and viewing patents is The Lens ([www.lens.org](https://www.lens.org/lens/)). Here is a link to [US20150244345 on The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_2015_0244345_A1). The Lens is non-commercial so you won't be tracked, has better search facilities and analytics and, if you choose to sign up, some useful additional features like collections and saved searches. I've made some searches where The Lens finds patents that are missed on either of the Google sites.